# Using a variable in @import statement - DotLess

Tags: css, less, dotless

I'm am using DotLess v1.4 and I would like to do the following:

```
// Variables
@Utilities-path: "../../Utilities";

@import "@{Utilities-path}/bacon.less";
```

When I do this I get a file not found error.

> File Not Found while parsing: You are importing a file ending in .less that cannot be found.

If I do this it works correctly.

```
@import url('../../Utilities/bacon.less');
```

As far as I'm aware this was added to Less in version 1.4, so I assumed it would work in the latest version of DotLess.

Does anyone know if this feature is available and if so what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Colin. Have you tried the variable name without the hyphen?

Comment: also, do variables in LESS still operate as variables if you put them inside a string like that? Have you tried `@Utilities-Path + "/bacon.less"` ?

Comment: Thanks @JamieDixon, tried both your suggestions but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is feature is not available in DotLess v1.4.  Version 1.4 does not mean that is using the equivalent version of LESS.

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/410#issuecomment-16219936 it looks like this feature was added in less v1.4.0 and requires the use of a mixin to do the import.

```
@Utilities-path: "../../Utilities";

.bacon(){
   @import "@{Utilities-path}/bacon.less";
}
.bacon();
```

Comment: I think that DotLess v1.4 does not use Less v1.4, hence why this does not work.